# Jhipster: get current user in NavBarComponent

Tags: jhipster

Is there a built-in way to get the current user in `NavBarComponent`? This component is loaded before the user ever logins hence, so impossible to get the current user from `Principal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.

1. Attempt to get account in `ngOinit` and fail.
2. Subscribe to `authenticationSuccess` event and try to get account again.